# Bad escape error when using a regular expression to remove punctuation in Python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am trying to remove punctuations from the text stored in the variable `clean_string`. Therefore, I attempted to use the following regular expression within the `sub` method:

```
remove_punc = re.sub(r'[^\P{P}-]+',"", clean_string)
```

Nevertheless, I am getting the following traceback error:

```
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-43-2954d0a309ca> in <module>
      7         paper_body_without_stopwords = [token for token in body_tokens if not token in stopwords.words('english')] #remove the stop words in the body and return a list
      8         clean_string = ' '.join(paper_body_without_stopwords) #convert the list into string
----> 9         remove_punc = re.sub('[^\P{P}-]+',"", clean_string)
     10         final_cleaned_String = re.sub(r"\bThe\b", r"", remove_punc)
     11         clean_text.append(final_cleaned_String) #add the string to the array

c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\re.py in sub(pattern, repl, string, count, flags)
    189     a callable, it's passed the match object and must return
    190     a replacement string to be used."""
--> 191     return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
    192 
    193 def subn(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0):

c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\re.py in _compile(pattern, flags)
    299     if not sre_compile.isstring(pattern):
    300         raise TypeError("first argument must be string or compiled pattern")
--> 301     p = sre_compile.compile(pattern, flags)
    302     if not (flags & DEBUG):
    303         if len(_cache) >= _MAXCACHE:

c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\sre_compile.py in compile(p, flags)
    560     if isstring(p):
    561         pattern = p
--> 562         p = sre_parse.parse(p, flags)
    563     else:
    564         pattern = None

c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\sre_parse.py in parse(str, flags, pattern)
    853 
    854     try:
--> 855         p = _parse_sub(source, pattern, flags & SRE_FLAG_VERBOSE, 0)
    856     except Verbose:
    857         # the VERBOSE flag was switched on inside the pattern.  to be

c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\sre_parse.py in _parse_sub(source, state, verbose, nested)
    414     while True:
    415         itemsappend(_parse(source, state, verbose, nested + 1,
--> 416                            not nested and not items))
    417         if not sourcematch("|"):
    418             break

c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\sre_parse.py in _parse(source, state, verbose, nested, first)
    525                     break
    526                 elif this[0] == "\\":
--> 527                     code1 = _class_escape(source, this)
    528                 else:
    529                     code1 = LITERAL, _ord(this)

c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\sre_parse.py in _class_escape(source, escape)
    334         if len(escape) == 2:
    335             if c in ASCIILETTERS:
--> 336                 raise source.error('bad escape %s' % escape, len(escape))
    337             return LITERAL, ord(escape[1])
    338     except ValueError:

error: bad escape \P at position 2
```

Comment: Python `re` module doesn't support `\p` unicode constructs.. you need to use third party [regex](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) module

Comment: Your error is `\P{P}` because  Python 3.6 does not support Unicode properties

Comment: Add more information to the question about what all punctuations you want to remove and also give a dummy input string

Comment: @RushikeshGaidhani you can find the regex in the question. This should clarify the pattern I am looking for.

Comment: What do you understand from that error message?

Comment: AMC - not much I'm afraid!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is on '`\P{P}` because `Python 3.6` does not support Unicode properties.
 You can try the following to remove all punctuation, except `-`:

```
import re
all_puntuation = """!"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~"""
dirty_string = "$<->311-abc(){}..//...-"
clean_string = re.sub(rf"[{all_puntuation}]", '', dirty_string)
# -311-abc-
```

[Demo](https://trinket.io/python3/e6a7a2a12e)

Comment: Thank you, but I want to remove everything but the hyphen `-`

Comment: nice, can also import string and use `string.punctuation.replace('-', '')` instead of `all_puntuation`